# How to find def-use chains at the machine-level in LLVM backend

Tags: c++, x86, llvm

I am new at working in LLVM backend. I have a X86 pass that I mark some machine instructions and then I want to find data dependent instructions of the marked instructions. By data dependent, I mean users of the instructions (like def-use chains). For doing this at IR-level, I used to use a code like this:

```cpp
for (auto it = marked_instructions.begin(), eit = marked_instructions.end(); it != eit; it++)
{
    for (User *U : (*it)->users())
    {
        if (Instruction *Inst = dyn_cast<Instruction>(U))
        {
            dependent_instructions.insert(Inst);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to do the same thing at the backend and with `MachineInstr`s. Also, my pass currently takes place after register allocation. However, there is no constraint for doing it before register allocation, if it's easier to find the def-use chains before register allocation.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think, maybe, `MachineRegisterInfo::getRegUseDefListHead(RegNo)` might meet your need.

e.g.

For some `MachineInstr *MI`:

```
    for (unsigned i = 0, e = MI->getNumOperands(); i != e; ++i) {
         const MachineOperand &MO = MI->getOperand(i);
         if (MO.isReg() && MO.isDef()) {
         unsigned Reg = MO.getReg();
         MachineOperand * mopr = getRegUseDefListHead(Reg);
         ....
    ....
```

Refer to lang-ref-llvm for details.

Comment: I have used this approach, but it not work. Is it work for def-use chain in a same basic block?